Why does Vercel keep throwing FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED when deploying?
I'm attempting to deploy a simple express js server to Vercel. When I attempt to do so, it throws an error code 500, internal server error: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED.
Though when running with node server.js it runs fine.
The server.js file:
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const storeService = require("./store-service.js");
const app = express();

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Middleware
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// ROUTES

// Default Redirect
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/about.html"));
    res.redirect("/about");
});

// About page
app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/about.html"));
});

// Additional Routes
app.get("/shop", (req, res) => {
    // res.send(JSON.stringify(storeService.getPublishedItems()));
    storeService
        .getPublishedItems()
        .then((items) => {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(items));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error:", err);
        });
});

app.get("/items", (req, res) => {
    // res.send(JSON.stringify(storeService.getAllItems()));
    storeService
        .getAllItems()
        .then((items) => {
            // console.log(items);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(items));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error:", err);
        });
});

app.get("/categories", (req, res) => {
    // res.send(JSON.stringify(storeService.getAllCategories()));
    storeService
        .getAllCategories()
        .then((categories) => {
            // console.log(categories);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(categories));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error:", err);
        });
});

// Unknown path
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send("404 - Page Not Found");
});

storeService
    .initialize()
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Express http server listening on ${HTTP_PORT}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERROR ON SERVER BOOT:", err);
    });

And the storeService file...
const fs = require("fs");

let items;
let categories;

fs.readFile("./data/items.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("File read error:", err);
        return;
    }
});

module.exports.initialize = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile("./data/items.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("File read error:", err);
                reject("Unable to read item file");
                return;
            }
            items = JSON.parse(jsonString);

            // Continue to read categories
            fs.readFile("./data/categories.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("File read error:", err);
                    reject("Unable to read category file");
                    return;
                }
                categories = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            });
            resolve();
        });
    });
};

module.exports.getAllItems = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("RETURNING OBJ OF LENGTH", items.length);
        items.length != 0 ? resolve(items) : reject("Items array is empty!");
    });
};

module.exports.getAllCategories = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        categories.length != 0
            ? resolve(categories)
            : reject("Categories array is empty!");
    });
};

module.exports.getPublishedItems = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        items.length != 0
            ? resolve(items.filter((item) => item.published == true))
            : reject("No published items found!");
    });
};

package.json
{
  "name": "web322-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "WEB322 e-commerce app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "accepts": "^1.3.8",
    "array-flatten": "^1.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bytes": "^3.1.2",
    "call-bind": "^1.0.7",
    "content-disposition": "^0.5.4",
    "content-type": "^1.0.5",
    "cookie": "^0.6.0",
    "cookie-signature": "^1.0.6",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "define-data-property": "^1.1.4",
    "depd": "^2.0.0",
    "destroy": "^1.2.0",
    "ee-first": "^1.1.1",
    "encodeurl": "^1.0.2",
    "es-define-property": "^1.0.0",
    "es-errors": "^1.3.0",
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "etag": "^1.8.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "finalhandler": "^1.2.0",
    "forwarded": "^0.2.0",
    "fresh": "^0.5.2",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.2",
    "get-intrinsic": "^1.2.4",
    "gopd": "^1.0.1",
    "has-property-descriptors": "^1.0.2",
    "has-proto": "^1.0.3",
    "has-symbols": "^1.0.3",
    "hasown": "^2.0.2",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.24",
    "inherits": "^2.0.4",
    "ipaddr.js": "^1.9.1",
    "media-typer": "^0.3.0",
    "merge-descriptors": "^1.0.1",
    "methods": "^1.1.2",
    "mime": "^1.6.0",
    "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "ms": "^2.0.0",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.3",
    "object-inspect": "^1.13.1",
    "on-finished": "^2.4.1",
    "parseurl": "^1.3.3",
    "path-to-regexp": "^0.1.7",
    "proxy-addr": "^2.0.7",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "range-parser": "^1.2.1",
    "raw-body": "^2.5.2",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "safer-buffer": "^2.1.2",
    "send": "^0.18.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.15.0",
    "set-function-length": "^1.2.2",
    "setprototypeof": "^1.2.0",
    "side-channel": "^1.0.6",
    "statuses": "^2.0.1",
    "toidentifier": "^1.0.1",
    "type-is": "^1.6.18",
    "unpipe": "^1.0.0",
    "utils-merge": "^1.0.1",
    "vary": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/MarletFisher/web322-app.git"
  },
  "author": "Frank Cheng",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/MarletFisher/web322-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/MarletFisher/web322-app#readme"
}

and the vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "server.js"
    }
  ]
}

Deployed the mentioned code, but Vercel keeps throwing an error (code 500) FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

This post might be helpful for you.Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031624/how-to-debug-or-handle-vercel-function-invocation-failed-error
